# Connect to tfspreview from VS2010 SP1 -> TF31002: Unable to connect

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have freshly installed VS2010 with SP1, and when I try to connect to a project on tfspreview.com, I get TFS31002 error:

[image: screenshot of connection rpoblem]

Google did not help very much. Anyone solved this?

Comment: Strange, searching for TF31002 gives a lot of links.

Comment: It seems that tfspreview must be replaced with "tfs azure" in google :) I found solution by searching for "visual studio 2010 connect to tfs azure", there are 3 useful links in first 5 results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/09/17/tfs-azure-set-up-visual-studio-2010-to-work-with.aspx) which has solution: install [KB2581206](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=212065&clcid=0x409) which enables VS2010 to connect to tfs-azure and use Microsoft account to authenticate. 
It works :)

Credits to [Tarun Aurora](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/Default.aspx)

Comment: Also, see here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce6cbf1-fb55-4a7d-b39b-8589634d846f - helps keep you fully SP'd

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why this is not among top extensions (after VS install I usually first open manager and install 6-7 extensions from first 2 pages) :)

Answer (score 0):

It may seem unrelated on quick glance but I had the same problem. My machine had a preloaded McAfee.  Even I hadn't activated it.

It was popping up asking me to register all the time. And I had always told it to ask me later and had in fact turned it off, but it was still blocking me from getting onto the Team Foundation Server anyway.

Whenever I uninstall the McAfee that was preloaded on the my new machine, it has started working perfectly fine. Anyone else who can't solve this problem with the mentioned answers above, and has McAfee on the machine, just give this a shot.

Hope it helps